# How to fill area bounded by two parabolas in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

How can I fill between two parabolas using Tikz?  I have tried with the below codes. But I could not able to fill the area.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2] 
 %\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
 \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
 \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$y$};
 \draw[color=red]    plot (\x,\x^2)             node[right] {$y =x^2$}; 
\draw[color=blue]    plot (\x,\x^2/4)             node[right] {$y =x^2/4$}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

It produces:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2] 
 %\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
 \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
 \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$y$};
 \fill[cyan] plot (\x,\x^2) -- plot[domain=2:0] (\x,\x^2/4);
 \draw[color=red]    plot (\x,\x^2)             node[right] {$y =x^2$}; 
 \draw[color=blue]    plot (\x,\x^2/4)             node[right] {$y =x^2/4$}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you could use `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[domain=0:2,axis lines=middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,clip=false,
 xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,unit vector ratio=1 1 1]
  \addplot[color=red,thick,name path=A] {x^2} node[right] {$y =x^2$};
  \addplot[color=blue,thick,name path=B] {x^2/4}  node[right] {$y =x^2/4$};    
  \addplot[cyan] fill between [of=A and B];
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]